# Convert MSSQL time with decimal precision into PHP time and MySQL DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, datetime, time

I am trying to convert MSSQL time into PHP time and then MySQL datatime. MSSQL time format looks like this.

`2011-10-07 16:55:37.337`

I want to insert this exact representation into MySQL database. To achieve this, I am using PHP.

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time))`

But if I do it like this, I am missing the last decimal part `.337`.

How can I insert this MSSQL time into MySQL using PHP including last decimal part?

Comment: You also have min and sec reversed.

Comment: And you have format inside strtotime().

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s.B', strtotime($time))
```

But I don't know if mysql timestamp or datetime will store this.  You might have to look at another way, either text field or don't include that or something with timezones.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's temporal `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` support fractional seconds. Please note that for `DATETIME` columns, the column must be of type `DATETIME(6)`. This only works for MySQL 5.6.4.

For 563 and below, you need not store the data into a temporal data type:

```
However, when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, 
it discards any fractional part and does not store it.
```

So don't store it as a `date` value, but as a floating point value.

You'd need to convert the MSSQL time into a corrected format in PHP using:

```
$date = new DateTime($msSQLTime);
$MySQLTime = $date->format('Y-d-m H:i:s.b');
```

In terms of timezones, you'd need to maintain the timezone data across the your processing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this would only work if I am using Mysql version 5.6.4 or up. I am currently using version 5.5.27.

Comment: @kidonchu don't store it as a temperal value, but a floating point.